# How are crypto wallets derived? Specifically the BIP32 Root key

Tags: wallet, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed

I realize this is a very broad question.  I'm not getting helpful resources from anywhere. White papers don't really explain the code, YouTube videos are vague or abstract, demonstration sites don't really show the work.

I'm coding my own wallet (I wont actually use it; it's just academic), in Python. And no, Im not using special crypto wallet packages; it would defeat the purpose of learning what's going on here.

I'm also using https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ as a reference to verify my work.

I've gotten all the way up to the BIP39 Hexadecimal Seed. I don't know where to go from there; it suddenly got complicated and like I said, references don't really explain much of anything. If anyone knows of a good source to learn the nitty gritty details of actually constructing a working wallet, for arbitrary coin, please do let me know. I'd appreciate it immensely not to keep having to ask questions for every step.

It would seem, judging from Ian's site, that the next step is to decide which coin I'm using, and to produce a BIP32 Root Key. The site would also seem to indicate this is done before deciding on a derivation path. How is this done?

Assume I know which coin I'm wanting to build the wallet for (I know there is a list of registered coins with an associated number for each, e.g. BTC=0).

FYI, Im not looking for python code; Im looking for a specific, detailed explanation on the next steps in the process. Something that I can actually implement.

Comment: I’ve went through that exercise before, take a look at https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools/blob/master/cryptotools/BTC/HD/bip32.py (pure python code) and https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can someone explain \*simply\*, but precisely, how the mnemonic seed phrase is used to produce the bip39 seed](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/114282/can-someone-explain-simply-but-precisely-how-the-mnemonic-seed-phrase-is-use)